# I want to disable beep sound in Terminal - Mac OSX

Tags: macos, terminal

I want to disable beep sound in terminal. Im not able to find an option to disable the beep sound in preferences. Could you please help me out?

-cherryhitech

Comment: `Terminal > Preferences > Settings > Advanced > Bell`

Comment: No prob. FYI next time, software-related questions go on [su], unless it's directly related to programming tools. That's why you're getting downvoted, such questions are offtopic here.

Comment: I will keep this in mind. Lesson learnt from down votes :(

Comment: Good question, why not just move it to su?

Comment: This has been driving me nuts for years

Comment: is there not a command line answer?

Comment: the answer for iTerm2: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/214513/enable-terminal-iterm2-sound-notification-exclusively

Comment: for iTerm: Preferences > Profiles > Terminal > (Notifications) Silcence bell

Comment: Wow life is better now

Answer (score 115, accepted):

**UPDATE:**

In 10.12 the setting is in Terminal > Preferences, Profiles > Advanced.

---

In OS X Leopard (10.5 and later)

Open Terminal.
On the menu go to Terminal > Perferences.
Open Settings > Advanced
Un-check the "Audible Bell" option. (You can also set "visible bell" which will cause your terminal to flash instead of beep)
In OS X Tiger (10.4 and earlier):

Open Terminal.
On the menu go to Terminal > Window Settings.
In the Terminal Inspector window click on the drop-down list and select Emulation.
Un-check the "Audible Bell" option. (You can also set "visible bell" which will cause your terminal to flash instead of beep)

Comment: is there not a command line answer?

Comment: here is for iterm2: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/214513/enable-terminal-iterm2-sound-notification-exclusively

Comment: finally... I am free

Comment: In 10.12 the setting is in Terminal > Preferences, Profiles > Advanced.

Comment: Even if you do this, if you close all terminal windows but leave terminal open and type something, it still makes those bell sounds. Even if you have the volume muted.

Comment: To fix that I downloaded a silent.wav file and then set it as the bell sound by doing defaults write .GlobalPreferences com.apple.sound.beep.sound ~/silent.wav

Comment: thank you! lord that was annoying..!